# my htaccess show page name instead of get variable

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)Products/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule .* Products/viewproduct.php?category_name=%2 [L]
```

I am trying to Get category name but it shows `viewproduct.php`

Comment: What is the original URL you are entering and what do you want to capture from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule Products/(.+)$ Products/viewproduct.php?category_name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Problem is that your rule is executing twice. 1st time for `/Products/abc/` and 2nd time for `` `/Products/viewProduct.php/ `` URL since your pattern is matching both times. `RewriteCond` above will stop this behavior.